# Get datas from an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How from this array:

```
Array
(
    [2017-04-10] => 0
    [2017-04-11] => 95
    [2017-04-12] => 101.67
)
```

I can get something like this:

```
$dates = "2017-04-10, 2017-04-11, 2017-04-12";
$price = "0, 95, 101.67";
```

Thanks.

Comment: use `array_keys` `array_values` and `implode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we are using `array_keys` , `array_values` and `implode`.

> **1.** [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) return keys of an array
>
> **2.** [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) return values of an array
>
> **3.** [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) joins array with `a glue`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805856)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array=Array
(
    "2017-04-10" => 0,
    "2017-04-11" => 95,
    "2017-04-12" => 101.67
);
echo $dates=implode(", ",  array_keys($array));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $price=implode(", ",  array_values($array));
```

Comment: Hello, for the dates, how I can have something like : `"2017-04-10", "2017-04-11", "2017-04-12"` from your example ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

1. [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will get the all the key from array as new array.
2. [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will get the all values form array as new array.
3. [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will convert your array into string with separated by comma delimiter.

```php
implode(', ', array_keys($data));
implode(', ', array_values($data));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = ['2017-04-10' => 0, '2017-04-11' => 95, '2017-04-12' => 101.67];
$dates = implode(',', array_keys($data));
$prices = implode(',', array_values($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Several of the answers on this page unnecessarily call `array_values()`.  I think the posters were just rushing their answers.  You can omit this extra function call and achieve the same result:

Method:

```
$array=[
    "2017-04-10" => 0,
    "2017-04-11" => 95,
    "2017-04-12" => 101.67
    ];
$dates=implode(', ',array_keys($array));    // 2017-04-10, 2017-04-11, 2017-04-12
$price=implode(', ',$array);                // 0, 95, 101.67
```

**This is the leanest, most efficient answer to your question.**

Answer (score -1):

The previous answers are definetly the most concise. But if you needed to do any manipulation on the data (like escape delimiter characters, or encapsulate in quotes, or change the date format or add a currency symbol), this might be the most flexible...

```
foreach($arr as $date => $val) {
  $datestr .= $date.',';
  $valstr .= $val.',';
}
```

if you need to trim off the trailing comas you could do

```
$datestr = rtrim($datestr,',');
$valstr = rtrim($valstr,',');
```